# I need to count a total number of the values through the loop which I get after parsing Json but can't make it working with Console Application)

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to count how many books were sold and every sold book has the status: "sold" (on JSON). 
Here is what I'm doing.

1.I parse the data using this code and it works perfectly:

```
RootObject myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

2.Then I use "For Loop" to get all "sold" books listed in a Listbox or just dsplay it within Console Application:

```
if (myObj.books[i].status =="sold")
{for (int i = 0; i < myObj.books.Count; i++)
{// totalbooks = myObj.books[i].status.Count(); }
```

3.And here I'm getting lost. Because, if I use windows form Listbox control then the code works perfectly for example, I add the parsed data to the listbox and then I just count listbox items:

```
if (myObj.books[i].status =="sold")
{
for (int i = 0; i < myObj.books.Count; i++)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(myObj.books[i].status);
}
label2.Text = listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
```

If I use the same code for Console Application this way:

```
totalbooks = myObj.books[i].status.Count();
```

Then I'm getting a wrong number. And I would like to learn how to achieve this with Console Application so that I don't have to use ListBox and count its items.

Comment: Switch the `if` and the `for` - loop through all books, *then* see if it is sold

Comment: `totalbooks =` will overwrite the value of totalbooks. You may want `totalbooks +=` to *add* to it

Comment: Another one: if `status` can be `"sold"`, then `status.Count()` will return the number of characters in the string (for "sold" this would be 4)

Comment: Yes, based on all the answers provided here I realized what was my mistake and learned something new. Thank you , guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

swap `for`and`if` statement:

```
int soldBooksCount = 0;
foreach(var book in myObj.books) {
    if (book.status == "sold") {
        soldBooksCount++;
    }
}
label2.Text = soldBooksCount.ToString();
```

Or you can use:

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
label2.Text = myObj.books
    .Where(book => book.status == "sold") // filters all books with status "sold"
    .Count()                              // and counts them
    .ToString();
```

See docs for [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Where__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Int32_System_Boolean__) and [`Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below linq query:

```
totalbooks = myObj.books.Count(book => book.status == "sold");
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the if into the for cycle and test again..